# How to structure classes in a large codebase

Tags: code-organization

One of the most touted rules of OOP is to keep classes small. This means that in a significantly sized project there are bound to be thousands of classes.

Logically it seems to make sense to combine related classes into various "subsystems" (or various levels of subsystem). My understanding of Demeter's law here is that a class in subsystem X shouldn't directly talk to a class in subsystem Y; instead subsystem Y should provide a façade to abstract the details of individual classes within it. However, in a complex application that façade must by definition be a large class. with many methods, even though it doesn't really do much.

So should I be using façade classes (presumably at several levels) to maintain a hierarchical structure of subsystems, or should I treat each class as a separate entity and use it directly?

Answer (score 1):

> So should I be using façade classes (presumably at several levels) to maintain a hierarchical structure of subsystems, or should I treat each class as a separate entity and use it directly?

Your focus should generally be on [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

For some classes (basic dtos, utilities that are invariant), just using them directly is fine. No need to implement an abstraction that provides no benefit.

But for the majority of your code, you will want to introduce decoupling abstractions (interfaces, messages, events) so that you can change the underlying implementation without breaking the contract between that code and its consumers.

That general pattern holds as you move from functions and classes to subsystems and modules. Some are going to be core functionality that would require wholesale changes if you stop using it. But most are going to want to supply some contract (a library API, web API, protocol, message queues, data buses, etc.) that abstracts away their implementation so that you can change the implementation without breaking the contract between the code and its consumers.

*How* to do that and *where* to do that depends mightily on what problems you're facing, and is well beyond what any answer here can provide.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a nightmare to maintain.  It just creates even more classes to maintain.

If your language supports packages, namespaces or the like, use them.  Use the language, or develop package naming conventions, to hide subsystem internal stuff from external subsystems.

But there's no reason that a class in one package shouldn't talk to a class in another if that's the right thing to do.